# The memory footprint of the Win-side software written by Tauri has been growing

Tags: memory, tauri

I used the Tauri framework to write a win-side PC software, which used Vue, which only occupied 40M memory when it was first started, but it occupied a lot of memory after a long time, and occupied 800M after 5 hours, and later I found that his memory occupation has been growing. Have you encountered this problem and how did you solve it?

I looked at the task manager for a long time and found that his memory is gradually growing, and in the software I use SetInterval function to send http requests on a regular basis.